# gitflow - make sure master branch stable

Tags: git, git-flow

**we use gitflow**

- when tester has tested our release branch, we merge
     release branch to master branch,  our tester not test on master, **how
     to make sure master branch stable?**
- tester has tested release branch name release1, tester has tested
     release branch name release2,  both release1 and release2 merge to
     master branch, our tester not test on master, **how to ensure master
     branch stable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for `rebase`.  Rather than blindly merging your release branch into master, run a `git rebase master` on your release branch.  In this way your release branch will wind up being master, with the commits it adds attached to the end.  I.e. when you merge the release branch into `master`, you can just fast forward (i.e. move the branch pointer up).

This means that once release is tested, and it is merged into `master`, **`master` has also been tested**, since (due to the `rebase`) the release branch was **identical** to `master`.

For your second point, the same strategy can apply:

1. On `release1`, `git rebase master`, run tests, and then merge into `master`.  `master` and `release1` are now **identical**, so `master` has been tested just as `release1` has been.
2. On `release2`, `git rebase master`.  This means that `release2` now has all of `release1`'s commits/changes, since `release1` has been merged into `master`.  Now run tests, and then merge into `master` via fast forward.  `master` and `release2` are now **identical**, so `master` has been tested just as `release2` has been.

Comment: This makes the assumption that the release branch can be updated from master at any time. The point of a release branch is usually that you want to get away from the churn on the parent branch, apply a few bug corrections to address critical issues, and release. With the workflow you're describing I don't see the point of even having a release branch.

Comment: @MagnusBäck: It doesn't assume that the release branch can be "updated" from `master` at any time, but that the release branch should/can be "updated" **immediately before it is merged**.  This "update" (technically a rebase) will cause the tip of the feature branch to be ahead of the tip of the `master` branch, rather than them having diverged.  This means that when you merge you can simply move the branch pointer ahead, which implies that after the merge `master` and the release branch will be identical (same commits, same code).  Therefore if the release branch passes, so does `master`.

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to reduce the amount of double testing (first testing the release and then testing master after the release has been merged into it), right? How would your proposal help with that unless you actually add the release tag to the newly-rebased tip of the release branch (to which master can be fast-forwarded)? If you add the release tag and _then_ rebase the release branch you still have two different source code trees to test.

Comment: @MagnusBäck: The OP is asking about making sure `master` is stable, not about reducing double testing.  My solution ensures that the release branch and `master` branch will be carbon copies of each other, ensuring that `master` is stable if the release branch is, and thereby answering the question.  Also note that the OP doesn't mention tags, rather talking about branches.

Comment: I think you're reading the OP's question too literally. If double testing wasn't an issue, the rather obvious answer to the question would be "test in both places". Now. Tags or no tags, release branches are for making releases, yes? If you don't tag the pre-rebase commit from which you're making your release, rebasing the release branch seems like a very bad idea. If you make the release from the rebased commit, what is the point of the release branch?

Comment: @MagnusBäck: If you test in both places, and the code on `master` fails, then `master` is broken.  If the release branch is merely for making releases, why would it ever diverge from master?  Shouldn't all merges of the release branch into `master` be fast forwards?  Also, why would there then be two divergent release branches?

Comment: Yes, if you test _after_ you push your merge to master there's a risk that the branch will be broken. But isn't that true for any type of change you make? The point of release branches is usually to allow development to continue on the parent branch without risk of screwing up the release. It's therefore natural that they diverge, at least temporarily. You get two or more divergent release branches if you have two or more releases that overlap in time. That's unusual in many projects but there's nothing inherently weird about it.